# How to add array data and display them in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am using following code in c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int functionIs();

int main()
{
    functionIs();
    return 0;
}

int functionIs()
{

    int value[3];
    value[0] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       value[i] += i + 1;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        cout << "Value = " << value[k];
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

Value = 1

Value = 2

Value = 4197152

What is wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Reading uninitialized variables is undefined behaviour.

Comment: The fact that the second value is `2` is just luck. When the loop starts, you should think of your array as containing `{0, ???, ???}` since you never initialized `value[1]` or `value[2]`. A different compiler, a different compiler *setting*, another variable declared, and the second value would be completely different.

Comment: value[i] += <- += what? You did not initialized that variable, check the robison answer for that. The data inside the vector is not initialized as 0, its just memory junk

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a value to every element in array `value`. You are only giving the first element the value 0:

```
Value[0] = 0;
```

If not you add to whatever was in memory at location `value[i]` whit this code:

```
Value[i] += i + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add one to the previous value in the array, not add `i+1` to each value in the array. Try changing the first loop to:

```
value[0]=0;
for (int i=1; i<3; i++) {
    value[i] = value[i-1]+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing uninitialised variables is undefined, as already stated in comments. The easiest to initialise all the elements of an array to zero would be

```
int value[3] = {};
```

*Aside*: When `i` going to be changing for every iteration and the element assigned is going to change every time, why use `+=`, you can just assign `=` and be done with it.